# Validate a Radio Button

Tags: html, validation, radio-button

I want to make a simple validation form, which will show warning message, when it will be  uncheck in a `<div>`.

This is what, i come up till now.

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
<b>1st question:</b><br />
Option 1 <input type="radio" name="question1" value="Option1" /><br />
Option 2 <input type="radio" name="question1" value="Option2" /><br />
Option 3 <input type="radio" name="question1" value="Option3" /><br />
Option 4 <input type="radio" name="question1" value="Option4" /><br />
<br />
<b>2nd question:</b><br />
Option 1 <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Option1" /><br />
Option 2 <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Option2" /><br />
Option 3 <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Option3" /><br />
Option 4 <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Option4" /><br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>`
```

Comment: server side or client side ?

Comment: i didn't find `<div>` in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by jQuery. The [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) attribute it calculate The number of elements in the jQuery object

```
$("#forms").submit(function(){ //or you can use click event 
   if ($("input[name='question1']:checked").length > 0){
  $('.show_message').html(' ');
  $('.show_message').html('selected  ');
}
else{
   $('.show_message').html(' ');
   $('.show_message').html(' no  one selected ');
   return false;
}

});
```

and

```
<div class="show_message"></div>
<form id="form" action="result.php" method="post">
 . . . .
</form>
```

[image: jsFiddle]